# MySQL Connection Method

Tags: mysql, connection

I'm working on a website that interacts with the database several times on a single page. At the moment, I'm opening a connection once at the top of the script and closing it after every query(at the bottom of the script).

But I read an article stressing the importance of closing a connection after each query, reopening it if another query needs to be made.

This doesn't seem practical, since it would noticeably increase the execution duration.

On the other end of the scale, I know some people don't even close the connection.

So my question is:
Which is the best method in general? Keep the connection open throughout the whole script, or open/close it for each query? And is it worth closing a connection?

*I understand there's other related topics, but they all seem to have conflicting answers.*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it dependents buddy :), usually some developers keep open the connection at peak times, but this is not nice to keep a (external) connection alive.

the best practice would be keeping connection open for a timeout, for example keep connection open for 10 seconds and after that close it if connection was idle.

also I have to mention about pool, databases usually provides connection pools for external access, it means database prepare x(256) number of connections, so the execution time will be decreased for the next connection, because they have prepared before, it dependents to the database behavior, for example a database would [recycle](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial#trpool) a closed connection again and use it for another request, while another database would create one connection and act with external requests as sessions.

but generally this is recommended don't keep a database connection open, because it takes some resources(external resources that you cannot manage them) that causes reduce the performance.

and +1 for good question :).